# Change sensitivity of UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer, uipageviewcontroller

I have an app from the page based application template in Xcode.

The problem is that each page is part of a notebook, so you can draw on it. I am doing this with a custom gesture recognizer.

The problem is that on pages with another page on each side you can't draw because it thinks you are turning the page, how do I change the sensitivity of the page view if the gesture recognizers are not in the storyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the gesture recognizers of the page view controller from the gestureRecognizers property. Then call requireGestureRecognizerToFail: with your own gesture recognizer on each of them.

Comment: Ok, But how do I jest change the sensitivity of them?

Comment: I get no gestureRecognizers with that api now.